# List all rows despite join

Tags: mysql, sql

I don't understand why what i am trying doesn't work.

I have two tables

```
Table1
id_tb1    |  tb1field
1            aaa
2            bbb
3            ccc
4            ddd
5            eee

Table2
id_stuff  | id_tb1
1           1   
1           4
1           5
2           1
3           1
```

What id need is to join tb1 and tb2 but also list all records from tb1. Something like this :

```
Result
id_tb1    |  tb1field  | tb2.id_stuff
1            aaa         1
2            bbb         NULL
3            ccc         NULL
4            ddd         1
5            eee         1
```

So I did this :

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.id_stuff
FROM Table1 t1
LEFT JOIN Table2 t2 ON t2.id_tb1 = t1.id_tb1
WHERE t2.id_stuff = 1
```

But obviously, it's not the good solution. 
Someone has an an idea ?
Thx.

Comment: Why do you think that the solution is not good?

Comment: Why do you think this is not a good solution?

Comment: @Kangkan Because `WHERE t2.id_stuff = 1` removes the rows where `t2.id_stuff` is `NULL`.

Comment: @AdrienXL you just want to display all tb2 related to tb1 where the tb2.id_tuff is not equal to null?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you add a condition on a LEFT JOINed table in the WHERE clause, this is just as if you where doing an INNER JOIN.

Add that condition to the left join

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.id_stuff
FROM Table1 t1
LEFT JOIN Table2 t2 ON t2.id_tb1 = t1.id_tb1 and t2.id_stuff = 1
```

Comment: Of course ! So obvious now you say it ! Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 3):

try this.

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.id_stuff
FROM Table1 t1
LEFT JOIN Table2 t2 ON t2.id_tb1 = t1.id_tb1 and t2.id_stuff = 1
```